# Convert IEnumerable to List to comply with method signature

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have a below code which is returning list of all the files. It is reading all the files from folders and subfolders and returning it back to the user as a list.

I have two cases in below code.

**Case1:**

- If `IS_PROC` is true then I get the `files` in different way and then return it back to the user.
- In this case I have a `IEnumerable` query which I am converting back to the list because my method signature is `IList`. Not sure whether that's a good idea to convert `IEnumerable` to `List`.

**Case2:**

- If `IS_PROC` is false then I get the `files` in another way and then return it back to the user.
- In this case I just have a list so I just return that.

Below is my code:

```
private IList<string> ReadFiles(string path)
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        if (IS_PROC)
        {
            // case 1:
            IEnumerable<string> query =
                from directory in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                let dev = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "dev")
                from file in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                let fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file)
                let dev_file = System.IO.Path.Combine(dev, fi.Name)
                select System.IO.File.Exists(dev_file) ? dev_file : file;
            // is this the right way to do it?
            return (!query.Any()) ? files : query.ToList();
        }
        // case 2:
        var lclJsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var lclTxtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        files.AddRange(lclJsonFiles);
        files.AddRange(lclJsonFiles);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log error here
    }
    return files;
}
```

So my question is -

- Does it make sense to return `IList` from my method considering what I do in both the cases?
- Also one of my case returns `IEnumerable` and other case return `List` so to make it compatible with my method signature I convert `IEnumerable` to list in Case1? Is that the right way to convert `IEnumerable` to List?
- Any better way to write the above method?

Comment: If you don't do `.ToList();` in Case 1, the query doesn't get enumerated, so the evaluation would be done by the caller (and the exception thrown in the caller code). But case1 and 2 are entirely different, you should use two separate methods

Comment: yeah even if I do two separate methods, one will return IEnumerable and other will return IList so at the caller side i was expecting list so should I change caller side to expect IEnumerable then?

Comment: If you want to return an `IEnumerable<string>`, then you can `return query;` in case 1 and `return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories));` in case two. But as Camilo pointed out, the behavior of an `IEnumerable` is different than a `List`: evaluation isn't done until the collection is accessed (which happens when you call `.ToList()`), which will happen on the caller's side.

Comment: I see so if I want to return `IList` in case1 then what I did is right? `return (!query.Any()) ? files : query.ToList();`

Comment: Why not just always return `query.ToList()`? `files` is also an empty list at that point.

Comment: Is there a reason for returning an `IEnumerable` for one case and an `IList` for the other? Because since `List` implements `IEnumerable`, you could just change the signature to return `IEnumerable`.

Comment: First you need to decide what signature is desirable for callers of your method, then you need to make the method return the appropriate signature. In many cases, returning `IEnumerable<T>` is preferable - it delays processing until needed and it doesn't require creation of another data structure (the `List<T>`). However, that delayed processing can make exception handling tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the method either way, it really depends on what you want to do. If you want to return an `IEnumerable`, you can just leave off the `ToList()` calls and it should work. You could also replace `GetFiles` with `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, since it also returns an `IEnumerable`:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadFiles(string path)
{
    try
    {
        return IS_PROC
            ? (from directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                let dev = Path.Combine(directory, "dev")
                from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                let fi = new FileInfo(file)
                let devFile = Path.Combine(dev, fi.Name)
                select File.Exists(devFile) ? devFile : file)
            : Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(path, "*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Union(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log error here
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can add `.ToList()` to the end of the return values and return an `IList`. Note that `List` implements `IEnumerable`, so you could just return a `List` in either case.

Comment: I see this looks clean. so If I decide to add `.ToList()` at the end then what happens in the case when it cannot find any files from both the case - will it throw exception calling `.ToList()` on null object?

Comment: What `null` object are you referring to? I don't believe either of those statements will return `null`, will they? Also, in your original code you're calling `.Any` on the `query` which would throw if `query` were `null`, so I don't think you need to worry about it!

Comment: The `catch` here ends up being *mostly* useless (except for the initial check on `EnumerateDirectories`), giving the wrong impression that IO errors would be caught. I'd get rid of the try-catch completely so it's explicit that the caller will have to handle the exceptions

Comment: Good point - they can do the logging and then `throw`.

Comment: @cs98 If the query returns no elements, or in other words, if `.Any() == false`, then `.ToList()` would just return an empty list (as there's nothing to add to it)